# Annotate fitted peaks with model's prefix

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, lmfit

So right now I have a fit routine that fits a composite model to a data set. It would return a graph like this on matplotlib. Is there any way to annotate each peak with the prefix of its individual model from the composite model?

Thank you!

[image: Fitted peaks that needs annotation on top]

Comment: You can use the `scipy.signal` package to find local maxima. See a generic function for this [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77921889/1910555).

Answer (score 0):

You do not give enough information about your code to give you a full answer, but if you have the coordinates of your peaks and the text you want to place at each peak, juste use [`Axes.annotate()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate). See [Annotating Axes guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html#plotting-guide-annotation) for more information