# How to automatically annotate maximum value in pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out how I can automatically annotate the maximum value in a figure window. I know you can do this by manually entering in x,y coordinates to annotate whatever point you want using the `.annotate()` method, but I want the annotation to be automatic, or to find the maximum point by itself.

Here's my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv('macrodata.csv') #Read csv file into dataframe
years = df['year'] #Get years column
infl = df['infl'] #Get inflation rate column

fig10 = plt.figure()
win = fig10.add_subplot(1,1,1)
fig10 = plt.plot(years, infl, lw = 2)

fig10 = plt.xlabel("Years")
fig10 = plt.ylabel("Inflation")
fig10 = plt.title("Inflation with Annotations")
```

[image: Here's the figure that it generates]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't have data of `macrodata.csv` to go with. However, generically, assuming you have `x` and `y` axis data as an list, you can use following method to get auto positioning of `max`.

Working Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=[1,1,1,2,10,2,1,1,1,1]
line, = ax.plot(x, y)

ymax = max(y)
xpos = y.index(ymax)
xmax = x[xpos]

ax.annotate('local max', xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(xmax, ymax+5),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            )

ax.set_ylim(0,20)
plt.show()
```

Plot :
[image]

Comment: I get this error message when running it: TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable - I have my axis data inside DataFrame's, not array's. Is this why I get the error message? Because just from looking at your code I know it should work.

Comment: Line 12: ( xpos = y.index(ymax) )

Comment: Tried in both python 2.7 and 3.6 , did not throw any error and was able to plot the graph. Not sure whats going on at your end.

Comment: Here, `y` is a python list. Lists have an `.index` method. However, pandas Series do not have this method; it therefore fails.

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Yes, Thats why I stated that `x` and `y` are assumed to be list.

Comment: @Anil_M in the answer you write "array" not "list". Since python doesn't have arrays, one may assume something different, like numpy arrays (pandas Series are numpy arrays). I think the fact that this answer uses python lists is clear enough from the code itself, but apparently it causes some confusion at the side of the questioner.

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest:  Thanks for catching that. corrected to list.

Comment: @Anil_M Yes, sorry about the confusion there. I got it working. I just quickly switched the dataframes into lists using .tolist() and everything is fine. Thank you both.

Comment: I would not recommend producing lists out of dataframes as a general solution. If the number of elements is low enough, you may however get away with that. In any case the solution using `numpy.argmax()` is faster.

Answer (score 48):

If `x` and `y` are the arrays to plot, you get the coordinates of the maximum via

```
xmax = x[numpy.argmax(y)]
ymax = y.max()
```

This can be incorporated into a function that you may simply call with your data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-2,8, num=301)
y = np.sinc((x-2.21)*3)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

def annot_max(x,y, ax=None):
    xmax = x[np.argmax(y)]
    ymax = y.max()
    text= "x={:.3f}, y={:.3f}".format(xmax, ymax)
    if not ax:
        ax=plt.gca()
    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=60")
    kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords="axes fraction",
              arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props, ha="right", va="top")
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(0.94,0.96), **kw)

annot_max(x,y)


ax.set_ylim(-0.3,1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just beautiful :)

Comment: Because there was some confusion about which method might work with which kind of input: The method presented in this answer works well with the input data being **numpy arrays** as well as **pandas Series**. Pure python lists will not work - in this case refer to [@Anil_M's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43375405/4124317) to this question.

Answer (score 7):

The method proposed by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in his [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43375318/3429115) is really neat, but it doesn't work if the data is within a panda data-frame whose index isn't a zero based uniform index ([0,1,2,..,N]), and it is desired to plot against the index -whose values are the x's-.

I took the liberty to adapt the aforementioned solution and use it with pandas [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) function. I also wrote the symmetric `min` function.

```
def annot_max(x,y, ax=None):
    maxIxVal = np.argmax(y);
    zeroBasedIx = np.argwhere(y.index==maxIxVal).flatten()[0];
    xmax = x[zeroBasedIx];
    ymax = y.max()
    text= "k={:d}, measure={:.3f}".format(xmax, ymax)
    if not ax:
        ax=plt.gca()
    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="round,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.1")
    kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords="axes fraction",
              arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props, ha="right", va="top")
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(0.94,0.90), **kw)

def annot_min(x,y, ax=None):
    minIxVal = np.argmin(y);
    zeroBasedIx = np.argwhere(y.index==minIxVal).flatten()[0];
    xmin = x[zeroBasedIx];
    ymin = y.min()
    text= "k={:d}, measure={:.3f}".format(xmin, ymin)
    if not ax:
        ax=plt.gca()
    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="round,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.1")
    kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords="axes fraction",
              arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props, ha="right", va="top")
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(xmin, ymin), xytext=(0.94,0.90), **kw)
```

Usage is straightforward, for example:

```
ax = df[Series[0]].plot(grid=True, use_index=True, \
                  title=None);
annot_max(df[Series[0]].index,df[Series[0]],ax);
plt.show();
```

I hope this would be of any help to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
infl_max_index = np.where(infl == max(infl)) #get the index of the maximum inflation
infl_max = infl[infl_max_index] # get the inflation corresponding to this index
year_max = year[infl_max_index] # get the year corresponding to this index

plt.annotate('max inflation', xy=(year_max, infl_max))
```

Comment: FYI, [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) is a built-in method to get the index of the maximum.

Comment: @Alex I get this: ValueError: Can only tuple-ndex with MultiIndex

Answer (score 0):

### For a single Maxima:

Set the `peak_distances` arg to a large number.

```
annot_peaks(x,y, ax, peak_distances=10000, y_position_modifier=14)
```

[image]

### More than 1 Maxima / Annotate Peaks:

Set the `peak_distances` arg to a smaller number.

```
annot_peaks(x,y, ax, peak_distances=30, y_position_modifier=14)
```

[image]

### Function for Automatic Annotation of Peaks:

For more than one maxima the we can use very similar code to [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43375318/1910555) `annot_max(x,y)` function; with a couple of important differences and a for-loop for each peak's annotation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale


def annot_peaks(x:np.array,y:np.array, ax=None, peak_distance=30, y_position_modifier=1):
    yindices, _ = find_peaks(y, distance=peak_distance)
    xmax = x[yindices]
    ymax = y[yindices]
    ymodifier = {k:v for k,v in zip(y, y_position_modifier-minmax_scale(y, feature_range=(0,y_position_modifier)))}
    if not ax:
        ax=plt.gca()
    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color="k",
                                connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0")
    kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords="data",
              arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props, ha="right", va="top")
    for xmx, ymx in zip(xmax,ymax):
        text= "x={:.1f},\ny={:.1f}".format(xmx, ymx)
        ax.annotate(text, xy=(xmx, ymx), xytext=(xmx*1.1, ymx*(1.5+ymodifier[ymx])), **kw)


x = np.linspace(-2,8, num=301)
y = np.sinc((x-2.21)*3)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

annot_peaks(x,y, ax, peak_distance=30, y_position_modifier=14)

ax.set_ylim(-0.3,1.5)
plt.show()
```

##### Find peaks:

Above uses the [`scipy.signal.find_peaks()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) function with a `distance` arg to determine the horizontal distance between each peak (i.e. smaller value gives more peaks):

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
yindices, _ = find_peaks(y, distance=10)
xmax = x[yindices]
ymax = y[yindices]
```

##### Annotation positioning:

Many peaks means careful annotation positioning. To specify an annotation's y-position,  a [minmax scaled](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale) value of y is inverted using a `q` argument. (This is later used as a text position modifier, i.e. `ypos=ymx+(1.1*modifier)`). The output is stored in a dictionary-lookup for convenient lookup.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
q = 1
ymodifier = {k:v for k,v in zip(y, q-minmax_scale(y, feature_range=(0,q)))}
ymodifier[ y[0] ]
```

- To manage different data magnitudes (e.g. `y=range(0,2)` or `y=range(0,1000)`), we can modify an arg `q`. For the data above `q=14`, or the nicer nomenclature: `y_position_modifier=14`.