# matplotlib mark out only the highest bar with its frequency value in histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to mark out the highest bar with its frequency value in a histogram created by matplotlib in python 3.7.

The data is dataframe of pandas.

Just like in this figure,
[How to automatically annotate maximum value in pyplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374920/how-to-automatically-annotate-maximum-value-in-pyplot)

but, my plot is histogram. I do not want to mark each bar with its value.

Comment: Please show us your attempt, so that we have context to frame this question in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method to plot a histogram with the frequency value shown on the highest bar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

# Generate data
data = np.random.normal(0,1,200)

# Plot histogram
plt.figure()
y, x, _ = plt.hist(data, histtype='bar', edgecolor='darkgray', bins=15)

# Compute the max value (plt.hist returns the x and y positions of the bars)
ymax = y.max()
idx = np.where(y == ymax)[0][0]
xval = x[idx]

# Annotate the highest value
plt.gca().text(xval, ymax, ymax, ha='left', va='bottom')
```

[image: Histogram with highest value annotated]