# How to calculate maximum value of a curve in matplotlib and assign that value (upto two digits after decimal) to the curve with arrow

Tags: matplotlib

From a data file in hdf5 format I am plotting three lines using

```
if (nbnd<3):
    color=f'C{nbnd}'
    ax.plot(x, y, c=color, lw=2.0, alpha=0.8, label = lbl[nbnd] if nbnd < 3 and i == 0 else None)
```

I want to grep maximum value of nbnd=2 along Y-axis and write that value on top of the line (corresponding to nbnd=2) with an arrow.
 A sample is shown in the plot where 0.032 with arrow is manually done while I need this kind of notation in matplotlib automatically.

A similar accepted answer is given here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374920/how-to-automatically-annotate-maximum-value-in-pyplot`  [`https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPwp7.png`]
But I could not get it done for my work.

I used

```
ymax = max(y)
xpos = y.index(ymax)
xmax = x[xpos]

ax4.annotate('local max', xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(xmax, ymax+5),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            )
```

It gives me below error:

```
   ax4.annotate('local max', xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(xmax, ymax+5),
NameError: name 'xmax' is not defined
```

[image]

Comment: What type are the x and y array you use? Are they `list` or `np.ndarray`?

Comment: I have a hdf5 format file that I am plotting.  I have updated the post.

Comment: The error `NameError: name 'xmax' is not defined` indicates that you didn't run above code as written. Clearly `xmax` gets a value in the third line.

Comment: What changes I need to do?