# How can I plot the maximum Y value on line graph from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, annotations

I'd like to be able to show the maximum y value only on the chart below.

[image]

code found below

[image]

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
axes = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.lineplot(x=df['Displacement'],y=df['Force'],data=df, palette="tab10", linewidth=2.5)
axes.set_xlabel('Displacement in X direction [mm]')
axes.set_ylabel('Applied Force [N]')
axes.set_title('Displacement vs Applied Force')
```

I've had a look, but most solutions use a list rather than a dataframe, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You can use `df['Force']` and `df['Displacement']` as if they were lists (or numpy arrays). The code will be the same. How do you want to indicate the maximum? By a horizontal line? A vertical line? A dot? .... Can you link to a matplotlib solution you liked?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374920/how-to-automatically-annotate-maximum-value-in-pyplot this is what I was looking at . Ideally the second example with the arrow is what I'm after.

Comment: Seems like you can use that answer to solve your question.

Comment: my bad , forgot it was in a function  :( easily solved in the end.Thanks