# Does plt.scatter function in Python include all points when used?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was using the plt.scatter function in Python, and I just wondered whether it includes all the values that it's supposed to plot, of if it in some way excludes small and large values, for instance.

Comment: What makes you think it would? If some of the data points are missing, it is most likely because of your code which you did not include in your question. I suggest reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also points with one of the coordinates `NaN` ("Not a number") or infinity will be skipped.

Comment: If for whatever reason you need to confirm that it does include all the values, you can get the maximum with something like `max(mydata)` and then follow the answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374920/how-to-automatically-annotate-maximum-value-in-pyplot) to annotate the location and value of the max on your plot.